# DB2 Community edition on higher core count server

Tags: db2

If I run DB2 community edition on a higher core count server will IBM want to charge me for more cores or will the software simply use only 4 cores and 16gb of memory?

Comment: The answer is "both". And licensing questions are off-topic on this site.

Comment: Why would it be both? If it only runs on 4 cores

Comment: Why would IBM not _want_ to charge you more?

Comment: I understand they always want to SELL more but would they SUE me for using only 4 cores? In other words is the community edition inherently restricted to 4 cores?

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. As pointed out by mustaccio in the first comment: "_licensing questions are off-topic on this site_". The reason being as they unfolded in the comments section. Please contact your local software vendor of trust, a local software consultant, or even better a local IBM representative to receive adequate and legitimate answers to your question. There are some rare cases where you might receive a recommendation or an advice here on DBA.SE, but if you get sued, then you get sued and no hint at any Q&A is going to save your dollars.  Thank you.